Xcode doesn't show all symbol names in backtrace when Unit Testing
When I add breakpoint into the unit test, it stops properly, however the items in backtrace shows as 0x1... (for functions from within the application under test). It does that in when i type bt into lldb command line too - See the screenshot, the selected item on the left-hand side and lldb output at the bottom.
It also completely fails to stop on any breakpoints set within the app.
Therefore I believe the lldb doesn't have the dsym file of the app loaded. Is there any way to make Xcode load that automatically/manually?
I do have the Debug executable checked in the Test build scheme, some/most of the tests also pass successfully.
This is what i can see: 
How can I get Xcode to show a symbolicated backtrace for apps I build?
